# Intuit Quickbooks Integration with .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I've been doing some research on this subject and have not come up with much of a solution.  Is there any known way to integrate Intuit Quickbooks with a .Net Core application?  As of right now, the SDK does not support core.

The functionality I need is to be able to create invoices in Quickbooks (Desktop version) with data collected in my .Net Core application.

Is there some sort of API available that I can hit with simple http requests from my application?

Or is there a good way to create a .iif (Intuit Interchange Format) file from my application that can be imported as an invoice into Quickbooks. (This approach looks very complicated from what I've seen)

Any information on the subject is appreciated!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: I believe this question is valid.  Since we're quoting: "if your question generally covers...software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!".  .NET Core and Quickbooks are both tools that have massive developer communities.  The question is answerable.

Comment: @big_water did you find the solution to this issue. I am having the same problem and their docs don't seem to do the good job of explaining what is available. Any help would be great Thank you

Comment: @Virodh for QB Online, they have a REST API that is easily accessible.  For QB Desktop, I ended up going the route of building a standalone Full .NET solution which uses QBFC to communicate to quickbooks and create invoices.  More info available here: https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/develop/sample-applications-and-code

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but still relevant.  The quick answer is Intuit has no plans to support DotNetCore (including DotNet5,DotNet6 & DotNet7[still in beta]) for their desktop versions of Quickbooks.  The plan is to support desktop versions only for a few more years, then it will be abandoned completely in favor of their Web/Cloud-only version.  This is part of their SAAS goal.
Fortunately, DotNet4.x is built into Windows 10 & 11, so you can go ahead and use it with no worries.